# Quote Approval that Notifies a Manager by E-mail (no action required from the manager)

Tags: approval-process, email-alert, notification

I want to be able to add a notification e-mail to my approval process when a quote is approved.

Here are the approval processes that I have right now....

- Over $100k List Price

  1. Rep submits quote for review
  2. Manager 1 needs to approve
  3. Manager 2 needs to approve right after Manager 1 Approves
  4. After both managers approve, the Rep is notified by e-mail that his/her quote is approved
- Under $100k List Price

  1. Rep submits quote for review
  2. Manager 1 needs to approve
  3. After Manager 1 approves, the Rep is notified by e-mail that his/her quote is approved

So for the Under $100k List Price approval process, how can I add it so that Manager 2 is notified about the approved quote?

- Under $100k List Price

  1. Rep submits quote for review
  2. Manager 1 needs to approve
  3. After Manager 1 approves, the Rep is notified by e-mail that his/her quote is approved

***4. Manager 2 will be notified by e-mail that the Rep's quote has been approved, but no action is required.***

Thanks in advance!

Comment: one approach is to add a custom field of type email with value of manager2 - and populate with trigger or wf field update. This will make the manager2 value available to the email alert used in the under $100K list price approval flow.